# Bitmap is not drawn on canvas - android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-image, bitmapfactory

In my android application,I am drawing a `bitmap` on `canvas`.Here, i have created `customView` and inflating that view in my layout.These all works perfectly.But i am facing one weird problem, If i debug my application, then bitmap is drawn on canvas,but if i install this app on device then sometimes it doesn't draw bitmap on canvas and shows blank screen. This error occurs with some devices only.I am testing my application in "Samsung Galaxy 3" device. How to solve this issue ? Please suggest any solution.
Thank you.

Comment: is it throwing any error like "outOfMemoryError" ?

Comment: no..its not throwing any kind of error.

Comment: in general, code is quite helpful if you are supposed to figure out a mistake :)

Comment: @zanky please post the relative code

Comment: Is it possible that device might be clearing cache and therefore my bitmap is not displayed.,but i haven't stored my bitmap in cache then why its doing it ?

Comment: I solved my problem. I was using one static field to store ID of resource drawable. This static field i was using across different activities. The device was not saving the state of this field and therefore i was not getting any value after some time. So, i decided to solve this issue by storing this field value in `SharedPreferences` and it worked.